# How would you write a CURL command that inputs a username and password into a form?

Tags: forms, curl, input, authentication

Inputs a username and password to the class="form-control input-txt".
Would you put the username and password in the header or the data section of the CURL? How do you specify that the username info goes to the username section? And, How do you click the button to submit the form?

I tried the curl below, but it doesn't work. I feel I'm way off. It uses digest access authentication.

```
curl 'https://<host>/ModelLoader' --data 'Page=login&username=abc&password=123&button=login'
```

I expected it to move me to redirect me to another URL and obtain a 200 success message.

[look of login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rh5rZ.png)

[html form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDX5r.png)

---
Update:
I now obtained the curl from using F12 -> Network tab, and selected a type doc and initiator, and it redirected me to the proper webpage. The current issue is that the curl contains a cookie in its header with all the login information + token.
How do I initiate the same process without the cookie? Therefore, allowing me to login again, once the cookie resets.

```
curl -i -k '<url>' -H 'cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=i3as0w50mm2jindljs4mm5mk; amlbcookie=01; iPlanetDirectoryPro=AQIC5wM2LY6ggczm9hx1rJ6MnzQQsHzt84XYctInhuFulpI=@AAJTMQACMDEAAlNJAAIxMg==#; .AspNet.Cookies=m-ePL1emLVo5RJaeX7RSd_1eQQkSCoMvdHNg2lzQXyiGM3h0F5YM6Z05ZZcXnT3VgSAdErl31R3_YIWqdJcrqZ3kcPly4oy-dpgz_h1nEl05Qa4rVjqViv52Srx3g0XaJ7Py6vES_Omh09YZn0W4--mGt0OXnPKmi-pso5-RdKmyeRd41-FginwYS9__4LvYoYLz7eRUhRm7h9vW_Bw9whlaxtpNy3o9j8yCPnM4vNHqXkA-egNUt7w5JIEONDmQ8mpgJ7313l5TI927Cw-ChM7940_HQpowR-NNh-a-NUZLetwWGCEIU12Z_Ob5rPfwIasvT2T2P56HGxIDT3Gl_a-_yiXPzvEtyNFePb9oOL29Q16fgrI0PxySibyMlGgLVT2ToLFQKQBmSiaPdlTxyu8QZB5KIP-DIjP1HpaCXRhwLMRrJ33O6afxulcspyDle4n1IoHa5m4LNFVy6ADcnv9gvHByqGX1NJnc6yYvg1WoP8wdkKHwjOD36Fq5XqgZuYAuI_7NruWg6IqFCYMZL0Uo5aw26UQ_4mLjRIaxupjI5itUPuzGeR4KnwtfQ99wAjws3wYs2BTNaDzJHHzgR4kFMHEtUk0Y6WKoPT0cBsQUfBF_GUJrGVOxyLaiQKnPs6VA_1Dg7Lav2kqfL4qhT4AbyaD60spsFoM31dWcevMGYeBVSSBt9PmjNsRZFyQPo3Aud1iAHufsOJLL7ijFzV5KC1a4rWrBaRm1a8E3iY4CK6O1za2wyJKezvNWLCPJzxw_-DD2gsZPkwtFgPKZmNs1qpRYdBqjuGmnHj6XfANgVkAhDnZIsXX7AlIf8xzWpXo2_WsVBxDRdunSCwMlL2M_mfN8jYYA2-3K-G_yCusHA5CBrMQm7eq7Qx8ewi4y0nYDnQgG77wUoSQZhphzrL7Yy2afA07JFHl01DGUWD9U25o6_cThlUoKaWEACYFjzYph-jyFrXprMhuenwd4gnQ-V0tyNH3G7RupxOAdaBfLDEblXtdls8p1QMMH0WHrkrVon-7YgsTXRql3idEO4BGm78LBNOvd34HNURcQybhuNHlJjLZcuI6ZFzyM6L_4QJ3nyQ-EtO2Zn2yxAIp1lNyWU1fINMKsUW9K56e5g8MK2eFom7lWvnypEg0dmfD5oqAOTndIga3dTe83m6oRcNC-tazdM8HuJJ7FQrpBAKvD2HrY041AIN8fuPhK6F5IBtApngj9-z7TBbd1lilYjsUbl4y4twscQYHRwVhAVjGTkjmNN0j7qMpGzFBW0ypVEpBVz_2_bMrcMPiJmQhblHTPoqW2ZBFYz0tP65HMPVjPv1YNz2YzxsmB5LBq3BFPDi4oMZ9G1YquvrpUeL_a0W5Q_EMeqAVoRWc2yK6ZKAKFGF9Spx4Wp0Glzu5Ts5PULSBriS77RGXummSG1QoFLzU0-PUxO91DiKKdlYvrYCiHYdUllvSd9Nxc-ovAC_TLa7Z_p5EZB_pQFbFvtZ-keDaNN1VMeOnxxUDkTs63_VB7WrmsBFJn6-KgkEa9jC6Fh9OtV4-XspLkdLKuT3hS3VqZxg5Pg3JdgC3eDhAXEMgNff1nBNHeiyc2zXTg1OmL'
```

Source code of the page I am entering my username and password:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Cinchy</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/cinchysso/favicon4.ico" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/cinchysso/favicon4.ico" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/cinchysso/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/cinchysso/css/site.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/cinchysso/css/cinchy.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/cinchysso/css/cinchy.login.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container body-content full-height-element">
        
<div class="login-page">
    <div class="fullscreen-bg">
        <video loop muted autoplay poster="" class="fullscreen-bg__video">
            <source src="/cinchysso/content/videos/network6.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
                <div class="login-div">
                    <form class="login-form" action="" method="post">
                        <input type="hidden" id="ReturnUrl" name="ReturnUrl" value="fakepath" />
                        <input type="hidden" value="login" id="Page" name="Page" />
                        <fieldset>
                            <div>
                                                                    <img src="fakepath" class="cinchy-logo" />
                            </div>
                            

                                <div class="form-group">

                                </div>


//HERE
                            **<div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control input-txt" placeholder="Username" name="username" required autofocus autocomplete="off">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group password-input-box">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control input-txt" placeholder="Password" name="password" required autocomplete="off">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group sign-in-button">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block-login" name="button" value="login">Log In</button>
                            </div>** //OVER HERE

                        </fieldset>
                    <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="fakepath" /></form>
                </div>
            

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    </div>
    <script src="/cinchysso/lib/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="/cinchysso/lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script id="redirectScript" src="/cinchysso/js/detect-ie.js" data-ieredirecturl="/Home/BrowserNotSupported"></script>
    <script src="/cinchysso/js/iframe-listener.js"></script>
    <script src="/cinchysso/js/iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js"></script>
    <!--<script id="redirectScript" src="~/js/detect-ie.js" data-ieredirecturl="/Home/BrowserNotSupported"></script>-->
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you use the F12 developer tools in Chrome, the Network tab will tell you what the specific site is expecting from you.  Look at the request.   Also if you right-click on the request Chrome can even generate cURL code for you.

Comment: I copied the curl that is an initiator and is of type doc, and used it. Though the result was gibbish. How do I make it not gibbish. And how would I pre-create the cookie produced, by providing the username and password to the form?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Are you able to provide the full source of the form, or the full request/response cycle from developer tools (removing your actual username and password please)? Hard to help you without a specific example.

Comment: @Jay I have added the full source of the form I am inserting my username and password